# Cookie not set and sent by Express Passport

Tags: express, passport.js, google-signin

```js
index.js 
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);
const app = express()

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({ 
    mongooseConnection: connection, 
    collection: 'sessions' 
})

app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: (1000 * 60)*10
    },
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {

    console.log(user._id: " + user._id); 
    done(null, user._id)
})

const GoogleStrategy = passportGoogle.OAuth2Strategy

const strategy = app => {
  const strategyOptions = {
    clientID: GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `/auth/google/callback`
  }

  const verifyCallback = async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

    let [err, user] = await to(getUserByProviderId(profile.id))
    if (err || user) {
      return done(err, user)
    }

    const [createdError, createdUser] = await to(
      createUser({
        provider: profile.provider,
        ...
      })
    )

    return done(createdError, createdUser)
  }

  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(strategyOptions, verifyCallback))

  app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google'),
    (req, res) => {
      res.cookie('???what is default key set by PassportJS???', req.user._id);
      res.redirect(303, `/loggedByGoogle.html`);
    }

I succesfully 
- logged in with Google, 
- passport.serializeUser was invoked
- profile data was saved in MongoDB,
- redirection happened to `/loggedByGoogle.html`
but no cookies were sent to client
and there is no entry in "sessions" data store after login.
```

Do I have to explicitly set and send cookies myself?

Only after I added res.cookie('foo', 'bar');
ahead of 
res.redirect(303, `/loggedByGoogle.html`); 
I got some cookie on client side.

I though cookies were set internally by Passport after "serializeUser"
invocation.
Is there a default cookie name (key) set by Passport?

What am I missing?

Comment: Check out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session

Comment: passport has something similar, but I haven't personally used it: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-cookie/

Comment: I think you did not take a look at my code.
I am trying to  store only session identifier on the client within a cookie.

"cookie-session" stores the session data on the client within a cookie
while
"express-session" stores only a session identifier on the client within a cookie 
and stores the session data on the server

Comment: Yeah dude, I looked at your code. I was just saying you might look into cookie-session to see if it might work for you. It always works for me. But if you want to use express-session, I don't use it so I can't help you. This is why I posted a comment instead of trying to answer the question. Good luck.